# Calcular cociente y resto de una division utilizando restas sucesivas

Tags: javascript

El ejercicio consiste en mostrar el cociente y resto de una división utilizando restas y estructuras repetitivas.
Tengo un código armado que en teoría debería funcionar pero por alguna razón no funciona y no encuentro mi error.
Mi código HTML es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="Ejercicio.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Ejercicio</h2>
    <form>
       <label for="valor1">Ingrese dividiendo:</label>
       <input type="number" id="valor1"><br>
       <label for="valor2">Ingrese divisor:</label>
       <input type="number" id="valor2"><br>
       <input type="button" id="btn" value="Calcular">
    </form>

    <p id="resultado"></p>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi codigo javascript es el siguiente:

```
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio(){
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ejercicio)
}


function ejercicio(){
    let dividiendo = Number(document.querySelector("#valor1").value);
    let divisor = Number(document.querySelector("#valor2").value);
    let contador = 0;
    dividiendo = dividiendo - divisor

    if (divisor =0 ){
        document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML="No se puede realizar la division";
    }
    if(divisor)

    while(dividiendo>=0){
        contador = contador + 1;
        dividiendo = dividiendo-divisor;

    }

    document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML= "El cociente de la division es "+contador+" y el resto es "+dividiendo;
    
}
```

Agradezco ayuda

Comment: `if (divisor = 0)` debería ser `if (divisor == 0)`

Comment: Esto: `if (divisor =0 )` está mal. La comparación debes hacerla con `==` o estricta con `===`. Empieza por eso.

Comment: Es porque tenes que poner === en el if(divisor===0)
Un solo = es para asignar y tres === es para probar la equivalencia en valor y tipo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ejercicio(){
    let dividiendo = Number(document.querySelector("#valor1").value);
    let divisor = Number(document.querySelector("#valor2").value);
    let contador = 0;
    //dividiendo = dividiendo - divisor <- esto es innececesario

    if (divisor == 0 ){ //Aquí va == para comparar. Un solo = es para asignar
        document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML="No se puede realizar la division";
    }

    while(dividiendo >= divisor){ //<- Aquí hay que comparar con divisor, no con 0, para evitar restos negativos
        contador++;
        dividiendo -= divisor;
    }

    document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML= "El cociente de la division es "+contador+" y el resto es "+dividiendo;
    
}
```

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Una explicación al código enriquecerá tu respuesta. Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Hola Mauricio, la verdad no sé que mas información puedo agregar. Solo corregi unos errores que tenia el codigo original y los señale con comentarios. Pero como no agregué código nuevo no sé qué más puedo explicar.